# Discretization into N categories with equal amounts of observations in each

Tags: python, numpy, binning

I have a numpy array of floats on the range of 1-5 that is not normally distributed. I want to find `N-1` cutoffs that will separate these values into `N` bins, where each bin has an equal amount of observations. It is not always possible to divide equally, but as close to as possible would be perfect. It'll be used on ~1000 observations.

I've created an example below with the requested method named `discretize`. The bins and cutoffs should be in increasing order.

```
import numpy as np
import random

dat = np.hstack(([random.uniform(1,5) for i in range(10)], [random.uniform(4,5) for i in range(5)]))
print dat # [4.0310121   3.53599004  1.7687312   4.94552008  2.00898982  4.5596209, ...

discrete_dat, cutoffs = discretize(dat, bins=3)
print cutoffs # 2.2, 3.8
print discrete_dat # 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, ...
```

Comment: Sorry are you after [`np.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)?

Comment: Yeah, that actually works if I just sort the data first. Thanks - feel free to provide an answer.

Comment: But wait.. then I still need to check what part of the array from np.split each value from the original array is in.

Comment: better to use `array_split` so it doesn't barf on non-equal bins, you could just get the first/last values in the arrays to determine the cut offs no?

Comment: I'm failing to do this in a simple, pythonic way. Do you think you could show me how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I just hacked this quickly, so this uses [`np.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) so that for non-equal sized bins it doesn't barf, this sorts the data first and then performs the calculations to split and return the cutoffs:

```
import random
import numpy as np

dat = np.arange(1,13)/2.0

def discretize(data, bins):
    split = np.array_split(np.sort(data), bins)
    cutoffs = [x[-1] for x in split]
    cutoffs = cutoffs[:-1]
    discrete = np.digitize(data, cutoffs, right=True)
    return discrete, cutoffs

discrete_dat, cutoff = discretize(dat, 3)
print "dat: {}".format(dat)
print "discrete_dat: {}".format(discrete_dat)
print "cutoff: {}".format(cutoff)

>> dat: [ 0.5  1.   1.5  2.   2.5  3.   3.5  4.   4.5  5.   5.5  6. ]
>> discrete_dat: [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]
>> cutoff: [2.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the code the find binning indices to fit my request :)

Answer (score 3):

pandas.qcut does exactly that.

```
>>>pd.qcut(range(5), 4, labels=False)

array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3]) 3])
```